# Is there a way to implement multiple classes into a file without having to retype the whole code?

Tags: java, class, import

I recently wrote a program that is a basic user/password JFrame password login. The code is, as usual, rather long. What I want to know is if there is a way to implement this code/file without having to copy/paste the whole class into another file. 
i.e. be able to reference this class in the intro of another program by some way, without having to retyping it.

This is the code I have:

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
    import java.lang.Math.*;
    import java.lang.System.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class UserLog extends JFrame  

    {

    public static void main(String[]Args) throws InterruptedException 
        {
        boolean isValid=false;
        while(!isValid)
            {
        // Components related to "login" field    
        JLabel label_loginname = new JLabel("Enter your login name:");    
        JTextField loginname = new JTextField(15);    
        // loginname.setText("EnterLoginNameHere"); 
        // Pre-set some text    
        // Components related to "password" field    
        JLabel label_password = new JLabel("Enter your password:");    
        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();    
        // password.setEchoChar('@'); 
        // Sets @ as masking character    
        // password.setEchoChar('\000'); 
        // Turns off masking    
        JCheckBox rememberCB = new JCheckBox("Remember me");

        Object[] array = {label_loginname,
        loginname,                       
        label_password,                       
        password,                       
        rememberCB};
        Object[] options = {"Login", "Cancel"};
        int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                                array,
                                                "Login",
                                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                                null,     //do not use a custom Icon
                                                options,  //the titles of buttons
                                                options[0]); //default button title

        // User hit Login    
        if (res == 0) 
            { 
                System.out.println( "Login" ); 
            }    
        // User hit CANCEL    
        if (res == 1) 
            { 
                System.out.println( "Canceled" ); 
            }    
        // User closed the window without hitting any button    
        if (res == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) 
            { 
                System.out.println( "CLOSED_OPTION" ); 
            }


        // Output data in "login" field, if any    
        String newloginname = loginname.getText();    
        String newpassword = new String(password.getPassword());    
        if (newloginname.equalsIgnoreCase("Cody_Coulter") && newpassword.equals("cheche1"))
            {
                System.out.println("Login Successful!");
                boolean selectedCB = rememberCB.isSelected();    
                System.out.println( "selectedCB: " + selectedCB );
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Object[] array1= {"It's about time to choose"};
                Object[] options1= {"Leave", "Keep Going"};
                int res1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                                array1,
                                                "There",
                                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                                null,     //do not use a custom Icon
                                                options1,  //the titles of buttons
                                                options1[0]); //default button title
                if(res1==1)
                    {
                        Object[] options2 = {"Answers for Algebra", 
                                             "Answers for APUSH",
                                             "Answers for Computer Science"};
                        Object[] array2={"Pick Your Poison:"};
                        int res2= JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                                    array2,
                                                    "This",
                                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                                    null,     //do not use a custom Icon
                                                    options2,  //the titles of buttons
                                                    options2[0]); //default button title
                        if (res2 == 0) 
                        { 
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nigguh you a cheatuh" ); 
                        }    
                        else
                        if (res2 == 1) 
                        { 
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nigguh, who's dumb enough to need to cheat in APUSH" ); 
                        }
                        else
                        if (res2 == 2) 
                        { 
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nigguh, you dumb" ); 
                        }     

                        String name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                            "What is your name?");
                        int length = 0;
                        length = newpassword.length();
                        String Pass = "*";
                        newpassword =newpassword.replaceAll(".","*");
                        System.out.println("Username: "+newloginname+"\nPassword: "+
                                            newpassword+"\nName: "+name1);
                    }

            }
        else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Username or Password!");
                isValid=false;
             }

            }
        // Output data in "password" field, if any    
        // Output state of "remember me" check box    

        }

    }
```

Can you just do something along the lines of

```
public class newProgram {
     public static void main(String[]Args){
         final private class UserLog {
                                     }
     //The rest of the new program
```

Comment: Yes, but you'd better move everything out of the main method. Before using Swing, which is a complex beast, you should learn basic stuff, like creating classes and methods.

Comment: There is so much fundamentally wrong here that it is way off topic to teach basic OO principals in this type of Q&A format, this is **too broad**! Read some theory and study and come back with specific questions that are actually answerable.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is little more than a single massive main method. Your best off scrapping this *completely* and creating it anew, but using object oriented principles from the start including creating classes with states and behaviors.

This is the best way to create code that is flexible and re-usable. I suggest that you get a decent Java book and go through it.